# R: "ExpressionSet" data not loading

Tags: r

I wanted to convert my dataframe of "array data" into an expressionSet. I followed this link and managed to get the same ( [Expressionset - phenodata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363991/expressionset-phenodata) ) .

So i here get my expressionSet

```
> test
ExpressionSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)
assayData: 1000 features, 733 samples
  element names: exprs
protocolData: none
phenoData
  sampleNames: X8261 X8164 ... X7727 (733 total)
  varLabels: Batch gender
  varMetadata: labelDescription
featureData: none
experimentData: use 'experimentData(object)'
Annotation:
```

But now i would like to load/use this object/data inorder to use this for a particular R package "PVCA" (http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.12/bioc/vignettes/pvca/inst/doc/pvca.pdf) , so I do this:

```
> data(test)
Warning message:
In data(test) : data set âtestâ not found
```

I get this warning "data not found". Can anyone help me know why do I get this? And what can I do to load my data and overcome this ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a function that returns a data set that the author of a package has included in the package. If your goal is to save the ExpressionSet across R sessions (this would not be necessary to use PVCA, just `library(PVCA)` in the same session in which you create the ExpressionSet) then use

```
save(test, file="test.Rda")
```

in one session and

```
load("test.Rda")
```

in another.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Martin. It works when I do this. But when I go further with the package till the step of "pvcaObj", it gives me a huge error "Error in exprs(vsn2(abatch, verbose = FALSE)) :
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'exprs': Error in is(object, Cl) :
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'vsn2': Error: object 'test.Rda' not found".

Comment: Look at the output of `ls()` before and after `load("test.Rda")` and you'll see that you now have the object that you saved -- `test` in your work space. Use `test` as the argument to `pvcaObj`, instead of "test.Rda". Check out `RShowDoc("R-intro")` and the help pages available with `?load`, `?data`, and so on.

Comment: Yes i now understand. Using "test" in the argument to pvcaObj works now. Thanks a lot Martin. :)